# Erro node ..version

Tags: node.js

```
C:\Users\Marcelo>node ..version
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Marcelo\..version'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Não sei como resolve, estou iniciando meu curso de java e tenho muito pouca familiaridade com os passos, dede já agradeço!

Comment: Deves usar `--` e não `..`. Testa `node --version` ou `node -v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber qual a versão do Node.js deves usar `--` e não `..`. A versão curta é só `-v`.

Testa `node --version` ou `node -v`.

Comment: Obrigado, simples mas eu não saberia sem ajuda

Comment: Dica pra vida: é padrão em programas que a gente roda no terminal, que nem o `node` no seu caso, de se acessar a ajuda do programa executando `<programa> --help` ou `<programa> -h>.